# Google Analytics and ecommerce profit share tracking

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce

I have a client who is working with a YouTube celebrity on selling a product (via WooCommerce). Links to the product will show up in the youtube videos and if the sale is made based on that visit then the profit from the sale is shared.

What would be the most efficient way to set this up? Is there an attribution model I can use in Google Analytics? Thing that I want to want out for is the multiple visits/purchases and the clicking back and forth.

Client wants all sales that resulted from the click on the link to be attributed to the partner, even if the visitor went to the site direct or from a bookmark in later visits and then bought the product.

Would using the campaign url tracking code the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into UTM codes and/or Campaign URL building

Campaign URL Builder tool allows you to easily add campaign parameters to URLs so you can track Custom Campaigns in Google Analytics.

> When users click one of the custom links, the unique parameters are
> sent to your Analytics account, so you can identify the URLs that are
> most effective in attracting users to your content.

More at [Google Analytics Custom URL BUilder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/)

These little snippets are added at the end of a URL and do not affect SEO. It is common for tracking and used by Addthis, Facebook and many alike.

Comment: But what about attribution for the sale? Client wants all sales that resulted from the click on the link to be attributed to the partner, even if the visitor went to the site direct or from a bookmark in later visits and then bought the product.